# Enviar hiperlink por email - quebra de link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Eu estou tentando enviar um `hiperlink` por e-mail, porém ele quebra na hora do espaço, no mesmo e-mail, eu envio dois `hiperlink`, um que não tem espaço nenhum, ele envia corretamente, porém este ele quebra:

```
 "Para visualizar o boleto acesse o link a seguir:" + "<a href=" + link1 + ">Clique aqui </a><br />";
```

Quando vou enviar eu já seto `email.IsBodyHtml = true;`.

Este é o link que estou passando:

```
http://localhost:44371/Download/Visualizar?fullPath=F:\ERP\ERP Teste\Erp\Visual Master Erp\Documentos\01001001000113\Boletos\1_1_CNAB240.PDF
```

E aqui é como ele chega no e-mail:

```
http://localhost:44371/Download/Visualizar?fullPath=F:\ERP\ERP
```

Já tentei enviando adicionando `\` no início e no fim, assim:

```
\http://localhost:44371/Download/Visualizar?fullPath=F:\ERP\ERP Teste\Erp\Visual Master Erp\Documentos\01001001000113\Boletos\1_1_CNAB240.PDF\
```

Mas também não deu certo, ele sempre quebra.

Comment: Mariana, tente substituir o espaço por %20, veja mais aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que codificar o seu caminho para uma URL. Para isso use HttpUtility.UrlEncode:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8

```
string url= @"http://localhost:44371/Download/Visualizar?";
string param = @"fullPath=F:\ERP\ERP Teste\Erp\Visual Master Erp\Documentos\01001001000113\Boletos\1_1_CNAB240.PDF";
Console.WriteLine(url + param);
string novaUrl = url + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param);
Console.WriteLine(novaUrl);
```

Veja no [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XV9vUC)

Comment: Obrigado, foi só adicionar `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` que deu certo.